# How to convert char[41] to char[40]

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Usually I do `strcpy` but here is looking like I can't copy bigger-sized to lower-sized array. I understand that I need to skip an array element for it, I want to skip first `[0]` element but how can I do it? I really don't want to write something alike `a[39]=b[40]; a[38]=b[39]...` etc.

Comment: Are both the strings always character **arrays** ? Or any of the string can be pointer also ?

Comment: there is char[40] and char[41], yes they are arrays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Play safe. Use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) instead of [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/):

```
std::strncpy(a, b + 1, 40);
```

It will work even if the last character in `b` is not `'\0'`, or there is `'\0'` somewhere at index `i`.

`strncpy` is particularly useful if `a` and `b` are not to be treated as *cstring*, rather they're just *buffer* which might or might not contain `'\0'`.

In C++, you can also use [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) as:

```
#include <algorithm> //include this!

std::copy(b + 1, b + 41, a); //b + 41 = (b + 1) + 40
```

I usually prefer `std::copy`, for it is generic and can be used with any *iteratable* type.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `strcpy()` with the arguments shifted:

```
strcpy(a,b + 1);
```

This will skip the first character of `b`.

Comment: Seems like still makes no effect. Are you sure it will work if a size is lower then b?

Comment: This will do shifting for you. But you still have to make sure that there's sufficient space in `a` to hold the result. EDIT: If you're worried about overrunning `a`, you *could* use `strncpy()`, but I'd be careful with that function since it doesn't always copy the terminating null.

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the source string, beginning at the second character:

```
char x[ 41 ];
char y[ 40 ];

/* ... */

strcpy( y, x + 1 );
```

Comment: Why are you typecasting to `char*` ? Array to pointer conversion is implicit in C/C++.

Comment: Old habit, as I'm usually a bit paranoid on warning flags... But corrected, as it's effectively more clear like that... : )

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you should use strcpy instead of memcpy. The following code will be efficient as for SSE2/SSE3 processors it will exploit the SIMD instructions.

```
len=strlen(b)-1;
memcpy(a,b+1,len)
```

If the length is already known

```
memcpy(a,b+1,40)
```

If you are operating on array

```
memcpy(a,b+1,sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0])-1)
```

If you want a safer approach:

```
#define min(a,b) ((a) < (b)?(a):(b))

......

memcpy(a,b+1,min(sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0])-1,sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])))
```

Comment: If `memcpy` is optimised for SSE, why can't `strcpy` and `strncpy` be optimised too?